# Proof of the limit of a recursive defined sequence $x_0=3$, $x_{n+1}=\frac{2}{3}x_n+\frac{2}{x_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

$x_0=3$

$x_{n+1}=\frac{2}{3}x_n+\frac{2}{x_n}$

The limit as $n\to\infty$ seems to be $L=+\sqrt{6}$.

I have already shown that this sequence is always positive. (so a lower bound would be 0)

Now, how do I show monotony?

Also: is strict monotony neccessary?

Or is nonstrict monotony sufficient? (not that it would make any difference in this case I guess)

Eitherway, you can read the appropriate sign:

My assumption is, that

$x_{n+1}<x_n$

For n=0, we get $$x_1=\frac{2}{3}3+\frac{2}{3}=2+\frac{2}{3}<3=x_0$$
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{2}{3}x_n+\frac{2}{x_n}<x_n$$
$$\implies 6<x_n^2$$
which is just some reaarranging of the terms.

But what we do now? Use the fact that $x_n$ is always positive?

I can't see how I prove this.

I never did a monotony prove, so bear with me, I have read quite a few, but I can't apply it here.

I would be happy about hints to do it myself.

Comment: use $AM-GM$ inequality

Comment: This sequence is not monotone, but the sequences of even and odd elements are monotone. Transform your sequence in a sequence based on the last two terms, not only the last one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Corrected 13 August 2021**

It’s enough to show weak monotonicity. If you show that $x_n\ge\sqrt3$ for all $n\ge 0$, then

$$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\frac23+\frac1{x_n^2}\le 1\;,$$

and the sequence is non-increasing. And this isn’t too hard to do by induction: if $2\le x_n\le 3$, then

$$x_{n+1}=\frac23x_n+\frac2{x_n}\ge\frac43+\frac23=2\;,$$

and

$$x_{n+1}=\frac23x_n+\frac2{x_n}\le2+1=3\,,$$

so $2\le x_n\le 3$ for all $n\ge 0$, and hence $x_n\ge\sqrt3$ for all $n\ge 0$.

Now you have a non-increasing sequence bounded below, so you know that it converges, and its limit must satisfy

$$x=\frac23x+\frac2x\;.$$

Comment: I don' understand your first  inequality. $1/x_n^2 \le 1$, but how do you derive from that $2/3 +1/x_n^2 \le 1$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: I had a mental hiccup and miswrote; it’s fixed now.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott how did you come up with exactly $\sqrt{3}$? Was that afterwards pulled out of the hat?

Comment: @Null: It was what I need in order to get the first displayed inequality, so I tried it, and it worked.

Comment: How did you get $\frac23x_n+\frac2{x_n}\ge\frac2{\sqrt3}+\frac2{\sqrt3}$? I get $\frac2{x_n}\le\frac2{\sqrt3}$ and it does not work (sign is wrong).

Comment: @Momo: Thanks for catching that; it was a major computational blunder that ought to have been caught long ago! The basic idea works, but the induction has to be set up a little differently, and I’ve now done so.

Comment: Yep, it looks fine to me now.

Answer (score 4):

The map $$f(x)=\frac{2}{3}x+\frac{2}{x}:[2,3]\to[2,3]$$ is a contraction because
$$\max_{[2,3]}|f'(x)|=\max_{[2,3]}\left(\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{x^2}\right)=\frac{4}{9}<1.$$
Therefore, by the [Banach fixed point theorem](http://Banach%20fixed-point%20theorem), the recurrence $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ with $x_0=3$ has a unique limit point $L\in [2,3]$ which satisfies the equation $f(L)=L$, that is $L=\sqrt{6}$.

Comment: You've got extra $x$ in $f'(x)=\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{x^2}<\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: @A.G. Thank you very much!!